# How do I use manifest.mf class-path for alternative main in same jar?

Tags: java, classpath, manifest.mf

I have created an executable jar file that contains two main classes. All libraries are included in the jar and the main Main-Class works fine when executing like this:

> java -jar MyApplication.jar

But when I try to run the other main class like this:

> java -cp MyApplication.jar my.other.mainClass

It does not include the classpath of the manifest.mf and it can not find the libraries that are in the jar file.

Is there a simple way so that the other main class can use the classpath from the manifest.mf? or should I create two separate executable jars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a class that invokes the main method of whatever class is passed as its first argument using Reflection - and configure this as the Main-class in your jar. This way you can invoke multiple main methods from the same jar with `java -jar file.jar my.other.mainClass`

Comment: I had the same problem and chose to use a property flag to select what main method to use, i.e. '-Dcommand=....'. This allows for a default use that leaves out the property

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way so that the other main class can use the classpath from the manifest.mf? or should I create two separate executable jars?

The JAR manifest classpath is only used if you use `-jar` option, and conversely the command line argument is only interpreted as a classname if `-jar` is NOT used.  You cannot mix the two approaches.

However, this doesn't mean you have to create a second JAR file.  For instance, you could write a simple shell script to launch the JVM using the classpath copied from the manifest and the secondary entry point classname.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your problem is with libraries **within** the jar? What version of java are you using?

I suggest you try the following:

```
java -cp MyApplication.jar <add external libraries here> my.other.mainClass
```

So you only need to add paths to classes that are **not** already in the jar. You can use [wild cards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) to shorten the list.

Here is another interesting option, [Enable your unrunnable JARs to run with the java -jar command](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip127.html). It describes how to select a main class in the jar file and make another runnable copy.